# passing php variable to javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Not able to pass the php variable into javascript function.

```
    <p id = "demo"><?php echo $color; ?></p><br>
    <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $color = $rows["clr"]; 
    ?>      
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <h onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $color; ?>');">
               <input type ="radio"  name="radio" id ="php" value="<?php echo $color;?>">
               <?php echo $color; ?>
               <!--//<label for = "php" type:<?php echo $rpproduct_typ_color; ?>></label>-->
            </h>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
       function myFunction(a) {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a;
       }
    </script>
   <?php } ?>
```

But this way it works fine:-

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
         <input type ="radio" name="radio" id ="php" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=this.value">         <?php echo $color; ?>
         <!--//<label for = "php" type:<?php echo $color; ?>  ></label>-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

But i want to pass multiple values to the onClick function i want the firs tone to work

Comment: What is the value of `$color`, any quotes?

Comment: You have to have unique `id`s

Comment: What is a ``h`` tag?

Comment: inside onclick function there is dynamically created radio button and used h tag for onlick function

Comment: @spencer no quotes ..value of $color is "dark red"

Comment: When you look at the HTML that the PHP output, what does it say where the color should be? Could you post it?

Comment: I am creating radio buttons having different values . when radio button is clicked that particular value should pass and element with id=demo 's value should be changed . But this element's value does not change..

Comment: @php777 we are putting time to help you with question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629219/mysqli-close-couldnt-fetch-mysqli-in and now new question with similar code but another topic, which is fine. You need to close the question you solved, or come with status. I have ask you question there you did not answer and now Wala new post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629219/mysqli-close-couldnt-fetch-mysqli-in

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the braces of the line:

```
<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
```

The  element does not exists, hence I made it a paragraph.

```
<p id="demo">EMPTY</p>
<br />
<ul id="menu">
    <?php
    $colours = array( '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF' );
    foreach( $colours AS $colour ) {
    ?><li>
        <p onClick="changeColour('<?php echo $colour; ?>')">
            <input type ="radio"  name="radio" value="<?php echo $colour; ?>">
            <?php echo $colour; ?> 
        </p>
    </li>
    <?PHP } ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function changeColour( a ) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

Tested and working

Comment: sorry that was typo error ..now i have edited the code .

Comment: In each while loop, you create the same myFunction  javascript function... that's not how it should be.

Comment: That is not true. The initial code iterates over a result set returned by ``mysqli_fetch_array()``.

Comment: You have positioned the code "<?php } ?>" after the javascript code. Hence, each iteration of the mysqli_fetch_array, the javascript code will as well be outputed, resulting in many javascript functions with the same name / code.

Comment: I tried placed the javascript out of the while loop , But still the problem occurs

Comment: In your code you still use a <h> element, which does not exist. Use my above code as a start, change my foreach for your while and rename my colour to your color. My code is tested and works: use it as your base.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mistake `h` for a headline `h1`..`h6` maybe? Since there is no `h` tag in HTML, at least none that I know of. However, I'd suggest using a block-level element instead, such as `div` or `p`.

```
<li>
  <p onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $color; ?>');">
    <input type ="radio"  name="radio" id ="php" value="<?php echo $color;?>">
    <?php echo $color; ?>
  </p>
</li>
```

This would give me an output such as this, which works fine in Opera:

```
<li>
    <p onclick="myFunction('red');" style="background-color: red;">
        <input type ="radio"  name="radio" id ="php" value="red"> red
    </p>
</li>
<li>
    <p onclick="myFunction('blue');" style="background-color: blue;">
        <input type ="radio"  name="radio" id ="php" value="blue"> blue
    </p>
</li>
```

Comment: radio buttons works fine , But the element with id=demo,does not changes

Comment: So what is the ``h`` tag you are using? Cannot find it in the specs.

Comment: I suppose you are using faulty markup, that's why the ``onClick`` does not trigger. If I change my code to ``h``, it does not work either. But if I use ``h3``, the ``demo`` element changes just fine.

Comment: I wonder why you are using a headline here anyway (if that's what you are doing). You should be using a block-level element such as ``div`` or ``p`` instead.

Comment: @ user1438038  I tried using both h3 and p instead of h ..but it is not working

Comment: Did you change both the opening and closing tag? Can you edit your question and also provide the actual output that is generated by PHP? That would make debugging much easier.

Comment: Share your wisdom, what made it work? Also, feel free to accept and upvote any answer that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: <p> instead h worked ..thank you @user1438038 and jeffrey ..I tried the same before it dint work ..but again tried the same solution and it somehow worked ..may there would have been been typo error